# Register Bundles in the PluginRegistry?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to load OSGi Bundles from an arbitrary folder at runtime in order to use them in my Eclipse RCP Application. The following steps I have done so far to achieve that objective:

1. Create a new Plugin
2. Acquire the BundleContext from the Plugin Activator
3. Install a Bundle via the install() method of the BundleContext
4. Start the acquired Bundle via the start() method

After these steps the Bundle is in status ACTIVE and can be retrieved via any BundleContext. My problem is that the bundle cannot be retrieved via PluginRegistry.getAllModels(). Apparently the PluginRegistry is not listing to changes in the BundleContext. I need find a way to register my Bundle in the PluginRegistry. This is important because the PluginRegistry is used by already existing software parts, e.g. the Manifest Editor.

The PluginRegistry has no method to register Bundles. Is there a way to add them to the registry?

Answer (score 2):

The `PluginRegistry` class is a development time class supporting the PDE. Does this mean that your RCP application includes the PDE and is used (in part) for plugin development? If this is true, then you will need to work out now PDE works (which is something I don't know much about). I recommend having a look at the classes in the `org.eclipse.pde.runtime` plugin (not the internal classes). You should be able to work out with the debugger and looking at the code how to add a plugin to the PDE runtime. If you have further questions about that, use the PDE newsgroup at the Eclipse site.

If your RCP application does not include plugin development, then there is no need to work with the PluginRegistry at runtime, so I'm confused by your question. Perhaps you could elaborate more?

Comment: I’m using the PDE, because it provides a fast and easy way to retrieve **BundleDescriptions**. You’re right from an architectural point of view it would be better to retrieve the **BundleDescriptions** via the **PlatformAdmin** and **State** object. I may do that in the future. Anyway I’m still using the PDE Manifest Editor in my RCP and it depends on the PDE **PluginRegistry**.

Comment: Yeah,then you need to figure out how the PDE stuff works then, I don't think you will get too much help with that here as there are only a few people who know that well.

Answer (score 1):

During the development of Acceleo, we stumble upon this problem too as we need to let the user deploy Eclipse plugins, located in its workspace, in the running Eclipse instance (we also need to uninstall those plugins after that). Since Acceleo is open source, you can have a look at our source code on [github](https://github.com/eclipse/acceleo/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.acceleo.common/src/org/eclipse/acceleo/common/internal/utils/workspace/AcceleoWorkspaceUtil.java).

I won't detail everything here but you should find what you are looking for around the line 880 and after around the line 752. The file linked is our utility class for manipulation of Eclipse plugins in the workspace and Eclipse bundles in the running instance so you can find there pretty much anything needed to handle your problem.

Small warning, when we are deploying on the fly an Eclipse plugin located in the workspace, we deactivate its plugin.xml. Since most of the Eclipse tools are just looking at the plugin which are contributing to their extension point at a given moment and since they are not listening dynamically to the installation / uninstallation of Eclipse plugins contributing to their extension point (which can be done like [this](https://github.com/eclipse/acceleo/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.acceleo.engine/src/org/eclipse/acceleo/engine/internal/utils/EngineRegistryListener.java)) they may keep references to contribution from plugins that we will uninstall later which can create problem. This behavior is explained in detail line 775 in the first linked file.

Regards,

Stephane Begaudeau